# Can I work under a research supervisor in a doctoral program when that supervisor already has an ongoing research project with my current employer?

Tags: conflict-of-interest

Can I work under a research supervisor in a doctoral program when that supervisor already has an ongoing research project with my current employer? (I wouldn't be working on that project of the employer rather a different project)

Comment: Why do you think it might be a conflict? And whose? Yours? The advisor? The company? What are the competing interests?

Comment: Surely the uni. has guidelines and policies on this.

Comment: You intend to both work and complete a doctoral program?

Comment: Conflict of interest for me. as my employer has ongoing research project

Comment: @Azor Yes, both. I intend to work and complete doctoral degree

Comment: @anynomous Good luck lol

Comment: We cannot answer this. It depends on your supervisor, your university and your employer. Ask them.

Comment: I think it also depends on the research projects in question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do not hesitate to work with the same supervisor your employer works also. There is no conflict of interest if you work on different projects.

If you have the same research subject, and you are afraid that your boss becomes a competitor for you, you can change your topic a bit or even suggest a collaboration for them for this project.

Anyway, I would not recommend changing the supervisor - if you have started to work with this person, it will be quite difficult to explain all the things to another one. Moreover, it can reflect on your relationships in a negative way.